# match school district logo with the URLs district ID

Tags: css, ruby, url, ruby-on-rails-4, conditional-statements

Currently, I've created an app with 5 School Districts. Everything works fine, as each School District has their own School Logo in app/assets/images.

I would like to display each School District's Logo if the current URL contains that School District's ID.

```
Ex. 
###These URLs should all display the Logo for District 1
districts/1/students
districts/1  
districts/1/faculties
```

At the moment, I've found a way to display a logo if the URL matches a Districts ID. 
But this is very inefficient as I add more Controllers other than my StaticPages Controller.

```
EX. 
 If I have a url like this /events/1
 I will get an error unless I add the Events Controller to the conditional
```

**How can I change the code so that the appropriate District Logo will show if the URL contains a District's ID, without the need to add every other controller to the conditional?**

**VIEWS**

```
 ###StaticPages Controller
<% if  params[:controller] == 'static_pages' %>
    Welcoming Practices
  <% elsif @districts %>
    Welcoming Practices

  ###Checks district ID
  <% elsif @district.id == 1 %>
    <%= link_to "#{image_tag("bonsall_logo.png")} Bonsall Unified District".html_safe, "1" %>
  <% elsif @district.id == 2 %>
    <%= link_to "#{image_tag("chulavista_logo.png")} Chula Vista School District".html_safe %>
  <% elsif @district.id == 3 %>
    <%= link_to "#{image_tag("fallbrook_logo.gif")} Fallbrook School District".html_safe %>
  <% elsif @district.id == 4 %>
    <%= link_to "#{image_tag("oceanside_logo.gif")} Oceanside School District".html_safe %>
  <% elsif @district.id == 5 %>
    <%= link_to "#{image_tag("temecula_logo.png")} Temecula Valley School District".html_safe %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: So /events/1 would be events for district #1?

Comment: No, Events is it's own class. It has no relation to Districts. Therefore I would need to add params[:controller] == 'events' to make it work. But this could become a pain if I continue to add new Models/Classes.

Comment: Okay, good. Ignore option 1 below then. You probably want #3 (and store the image URL in the model). So assuming events belong to a district.. in addition to setting `@event` in the controller logic, set `@district` to `@event.district`

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options.. two of which are:

- You could set up your routes to be of the format `/:controller/:district_id` and instead of choosing the image from `@district.id`, you could set it based on `params[:district_id]`
- You could also simply rename the files to be district_#.jpg and include the file based on the district.
- You could also make sure you always set @district to the current district

PS - you should really be storing the file path in the `District` model/table so you don't have to create image_tags from a hardcoded value.

Comment: Yea, I've thought about storing the images inside the Districts Table, the problem is that I also need to display different links on the header and footer that are custom to each district_id.

Comment: That logic should still probably be in the model, just for some districts it will be blank and therefore you won't show it.

Comment: so lets say that district_1 has (a blue header, with logo1, and 3 links corresponding to that district), but district 2 has (a pink header, with logo2 and 6 links). how could that all be done in the model?

Comment: A `DistrictLinks` or just `Links` model that has a foreign key to the districts table. districts would have_many links and links would belong_to districts.

Comment: by links i mean, district_1 has an about_page, contact_page, faqs_page. where district_2 has a fun_page, evil_page, crazy_page etc etc. they are links to different paths on the site. basically each header is customized for each district. the css is customized too.

Comment: Still, you could use a model for that.. all depends how much effort you want to put in to make it as database driven (and therefore scalable to more districts), etc.

Comment: that makes sense actually, any idea on how i can customize the actual css with every district?

Comment: Easiest way is to just add inline CSS based on values in the model or even a free text CSS but be careful not to introduce vulnerabilities by allowing free text CSS input by anyone